# Far Cry 2: swap mouse wheel for changing weapons?

Tags: far-cry-2

I can't change the way the wheel works to change weapons, scrolling down switches to the previous weapon, scrolling up switches to the next. However I'm used to have it the other way. I can only bind other keys but not change the wheel itself.

Is there another way to switch wheel up/down, i.e. by changing some sort of configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking, you cannot change the mouse wheels actions anywhere in the game.
However, you can make any of your chosen keys act like the up and down of the scroll:

Go to: **Game menu -> Options -> Controls -> Weapons**. There are `Previous` and `Next` variables there. They act just like the mouse wheel.

[image]

You can also change weapons individually with keys: **1, 2, 3, 4, 5**.

Comment: It's not an alternative, though.

Comment: @Bora, it is exactly what he wanted.